# how to load /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/railties-4.2.6/bin/rails (LoadError) from /usr/local/bin/rails:23:in `<main>'?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

if i check version of rails it is showing an error that cannot load,,how to load rails?

ERROR: /usr/local/bin/rails:23:in `load': cannot load such file -- /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/railties-4.2.6/bin/rails (LoadError)
    from /usr/local/bin/rails:23:in`'

Comment: Could you add the steps to reproduce this error ?

Comment: rails -v (command is not working ,it is showing error like this /usr/local/bin/rails:23:in `load': cannot load such file -- /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/railties-4.2.6/bin/rails (LoadError)
 from /usr/local/bin/rails:23:in `<main>'
)

Comment: Did you try to reinstall rails ?

Comment: did you `bundle update`?

Comment: i am running rails in  ubuntu operating system, i didn't shoutdown rails server directly i closed command prompt, so it is telling that error, what to do  ?

Comment: you need to quote us @Shivakumaram when you answer us.